# Interaction terms in level-log regression

Tags: regression, econometrics, interaction, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have the following regression:
$y=\alpha + \beta_{1}\text{ln}x_{1} + \beta_{2}(\text{ln} x_{1}\cdot \text{ln}x_{2})$
How do I interpret the marginal effect of $x_{1}$ on $y$?
I haven't find anything about the interaction term in a level-log regression.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want to include a term involving $\text{ln} x_2$ alone? 
Anyway, if you multiply $x_1$ by $c$, than $y$ will increase by $\left(\beta_1  + \beta_2 \text{ln} x_2 \right) \text{ln} c$. That's it.

Comment: shouldn't I take the derivative of y with respect to $x_{1}$?

Comment: Well, you could, yes, but in my opinion that’s not an appropriate way to describe the dependance. If you use $\log x_1$ instead of $x_1$ it’s because you think $y$ responds (almost) linearly to an increase of $x$ by a factor $c$, rather than by an additive increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value of $y$ given $x$ in your model is

$$E[y \vert x_1,x_2]=\alpha + \beta_1 \ln x_1 + \beta_2 \ln x_1 \cdot \ln x_2$$

Taking the derivative of that with respect to $x_1$, you get

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1} =  \frac{\beta_1}{x_1}+ \frac{\beta_2}{x_1} \ln x_2$$

Multiplying both sides by $x_1$ and rearranging, you get something like

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1} \frac{x_1}{1} = \beta_1+ \beta_2 \ln x_2$$

The LHS is the very definition of a semi-elasticity. This means that you can interpret $\frac{1}{100} \cdot (\beta_1+ \beta_2 \ln x_2)$ as the expected change in units of $y$ from a 1% increase in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the interpretation of a level-log regression induces a non-linear effect of $x_{1}$ on $y$; that is, a percentage change in $x_{1}$ will provide an increase in the level of $y$.  This can further be interpreted the same with regards to the interaction term.  Switching the log transformation of $x$ and $y$ will change the magnitude, but still retain the non-linear effect.

Here is a quick demonstration in R:

$$y = \alpha + \beta_{1}female + \beta_{2}log(math)  + \beta_{3}log(math) \cdot log(read) $$

where $y$ is reading ability

Sample Data:

```
df <- structure(list(write = c(52L, 59L, 33L, 44L, 52L, 52L, 59L, 46L, 
57L, 55L, 46L, 65L, 60L, 63L, 57L, 49L, 52L, 57L, 65L, 39L, 49L, 
63L, 40L, 52L, 44L, 37L, 65L, 57L, 38L, 44L, 31L, 52L, 67L, 41L, 
59L, 65L, 54L, 62L, 31L, 31L, 47L, 59L, 54L, 41L, 65L, 59L, 40L, 
59L, 59L, 54L, 61L, 33L, 44L, 59L, 62L, 39L, 37L, 39L, 57L, 49L, 
46L, 62L, 44L, 33L, 42L, 41L, 54L, 39L, 43L, 33L, 44L, 54L, 67L, 
59L, 45L, 40L, 61L, 59L, 36L, 41L, 59L, 49L, 59L, 65L, 41L, 62L, 
41L, 49L, 31L, 49L, 62L, 49L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 65L, 65L, 44L, 
63L, 60L, 59L, 46L, 52L, 59L, 54L, 62L, 35L, 54L, 65L, 52L, 50L, 
59L, 65L, 61L, 44L, 54L, 67L, 57L, 47L, 54L, 52L, 52L, 46L, 62L, 
57L, 41L, 53L, 49L, 35L, 59L, 65L, 62L, 54L, 59L, 63L, 59L, 52L, 
41L, 49L, 46L, 54L, 42L, 57L, 59L, 52L, 62L, 52L, 41L, 55L, 37L, 
54L, 57L, 54L, 62L, 59L, 55L, 57L, 39L, 67L, 62L, 50L, 61L, 62L, 
59L, 44L, 59L, 54L, 62L, 60L, 57L, 46L, 36L, 59L, 49L, 60L, 67L, 
54L, 52L, 65L, 62L, 49L, 67L, 65L, 67L, 65L, 54L, 44L, 62L, 46L, 
54L, 57L, 52L, 59L, 65L, 59L, 46L, 41L, 62L, 65L), female = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
    math = c(41L, 53L, 54L, 47L, 57L, 51L, 42L, 45L, 54L, 52L, 
    51L, 51L, 71L, 57L, 50L, 43L, 51L, 60L, 62L, 57L, 35L, 75L, 
    45L, 57L, 45L, 46L, 66L, 57L, 49L, 49L, 57L, 64L, 63L, 57L, 
    50L, 58L, 75L, 68L, 44L, 40L, 41L, 62L, 57L, 43L, 48L, 63L, 
    39L, 70L, 63L, 59L, 61L, 38L, 61L, 49L, 73L, 44L, 42L, 39L, 
    55L, 52L, 45L, 61L, 39L, 41L, 50L, 40L, 60L, 47L, 59L, 49L, 
    46L, 58L, 71L, 58L, 46L, 43L, 54L, 56L, 46L, 54L, 57L, 54L, 
    71L, 48L, 40L, 64L, 51L, 39L, 40L, 61L, 66L, 49L, 65L, 52L, 
    46L, 61L, 72L, 71L, 40L, 69L, 64L, 56L, 49L, 54L, 53L, 66L, 
    67L, 40L, 46L, 69L, 40L, 41L, 57L, 58L, 57L, 37L, 55L, 62L, 
    64L, 40L, 50L, 46L, 53L, 52L, 45L, 56L, 45L, 54L, 56L, 41L, 
    54L, 72L, 56L, 47L, 49L, 60L, 54L, 55L, 33L, 49L, 43L, 50L, 
    52L, 48L, 58L, 43L, 41L, 43L, 46L, 44L, 43L, 61L, 40L, 49L, 
    56L, 61L, 50L, 51L, 42L, 67L, 53L, 50L, 51L, 72L, 48L, 40L, 
    53L, 39L, 63L, 51L, 45L, 39L, 42L, 62L, 44L, 65L, 63L, 54L, 
    45L, 60L, 49L, 48L, 57L, 55L, 66L, 64L, 55L, 42L, 56L, 53L, 
    41L, 42L, 53L, 42L, 60L, 52L, 38L, 57L, 58L, 65L), read = c(57L, 
    68L, 44L, 63L, 47L, 44L, 50L, 34L, 63L, 57L, 60L, 57L, 73L, 
    54L, 45L, 42L, 47L, 57L, 68L, 55L, 63L, 63L, 50L, 60L, 37L, 
    34L, 65L, 47L, 44L, 52L, 42L, 76L, 65L, 42L, 52L, 60L, 68L, 
    65L, 47L, 39L, 47L, 55L, 52L, 42L, 65L, 55L, 50L, 65L, 47L, 
    57L, 53L, 39L, 44L, 63L, 73L, 39L, 37L, 42L, 63L, 48L, 50L, 
    47L, 44L, 34L, 50L, 44L, 60L, 47L, 63L, 50L, 44L, 60L, 73L, 
    68L, 55L, 47L, 55L, 68L, 31L, 47L, 63L, 36L, 68L, 63L, 55L, 
    55L, 52L, 34L, 50L, 55L, 52L, 63L, 68L, 39L, 44L, 50L, 71L, 
    63L, 34L, 63L, 68L, 47L, 47L, 63L, 52L, 55L, 60L, 35L, 47L, 
    71L, 57L, 44L, 65L, 68L, 73L, 36L, 43L, 73L, 52L, 41L, 60L, 
    50L, 50L, 47L, 47L, 55L, 50L, 39L, 50L, 34L, 57L, 57L, 68L, 
    42L, 61L, 76L, 47L, 46L, 39L, 52L, 28L, 42L, 47L, 47L, 52L, 
    47L, 50L, 44L, 47L, 45L, 47L, 65L, 43L, 47L, 57L, 68L, 52L, 
    42L, 42L, 66L, 47L, 57L, 47L, 57L, 52L, 44L, 50L, 39L, 57L, 
    57L, 42L, 47L, 42L, 60L, 44L, 63L, 65L, 39L, 50L, 52L, 60L, 
    44L, 52L, 55L, 50L, 65L, 52L, 47L, 63L, 50L, 42L, 36L, 50L, 
    41L, 47L, 55L, 42L, 57L, 55L, 63L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), .Names = c("write", "female", "math", "read"))
```

Regression Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
fit <- lm(write ~ female + log(math) + log(math)*log(read), data = df)

ggplot(df, aes(log(math), write)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()

fit

>Call:
lm(formula = write ~ female + log(math) + log(math) * log(read), 
    data = df)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)           femalemale            log(math)            log(read)  log(math):log(read)  
           -181.870               -5.403               43.434               39.116               -5.676
```

[image]